# Any open source pop3-connectors for MS Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-server-2010

I've installed ms exchange 2010 but without small biz server (we're on win 2008 server), there's no pop3 connector anymore. Anyone know of a good open source alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working with MS Exchange 2010 and successfully tested with 2013. I can make no statement about the stability yet. It seems more or less inactive.

http://www.pop2owa.com/

Answer (score -2):

There is but it's disabled by default !!! See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124934.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's something different from a POP3 Connector: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP3_Connector